# How to align a Column's child to the bottom

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to build a generic home page and I want to align the last child of my column (which contains all the widgets for the page) to the bottom of the screen but the widget wrapped in the Align is not moving. The following is what makes the most sense to me:

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[
    ChildA(),
    ChildB(),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: BottomAlignedChild()
    )
  ]
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: Try adding `new Flexible(child: new Container()),` before the last widget. There might be better ways though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the last child is not on the bottom of the screen, is the column wrapping its children? I tried to expand the Column but it just disappears

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Wraping the `Align` into an `Expanded` is most likely the desired effect

Comment: @RémiRousselet not working

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer nothing in the logcat

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327933/2850120

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use Expanded to make the last widget expand to the whole remaining space.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Layout',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Align Bottom Demo"),
      ),
      body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Text("Text 1"),
        new Text("Text 2"),
        new Expanded(
            child: new Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Icon(Icons.star),
                    new Text("Bottom Text")
                  ],
                )))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the result

[image]

Another approach is using Spacer():

```
...
Column(children: [Text1, Text2, Spacer(), YourBottomWidget()]),
...
```

Comment: Thanks... This was very helpful to me when trying to achieve bottomLeft alignment.

Comment: This is scaling the corresponding widget to the width's size. @IrshadKumail's answer is correct and simple.

Comment: What if I want Text 1 and Text 2 to be center and then  the Bottom Text at its bottom . What will we do

Answer (score 17):

I have always used [Spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) for these kind of cases in Column or Row. Spacer takes up all the available space between two widgets of Row/Column.

For given example, you can try following

```
     Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        ChildA(),
        ChildB(),
        Spacer(),
        BottomAlignedChild()
     
      ]
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

1. Use **`Spacer`**:

   ```dart
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       TopContainer(),
       Spacer(), // <-- Spacer
       BottomContainer(),
     ],
   )
   ```
2. Use **`mainAxisAlignment`**:

   ```dart
   Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // <-- spaceBetween
     children: <Widget>[
       TopContainer(),
       BottomContainer(),
     ],
   )
   ```
3. Combine **`Expanded`** and **`Align`**:

   ```dart
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       TopContainer(),
       Expanded(
         child: Align(
           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
           child: BottomContainer(),
         ),
       ),
     ],
   )
   ```

---

**Screenshot (same for all)**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are flexible to change column to a stack, you can do the following.

```
body: Container(
    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Text('Text 1'),
      Text('Text 2'),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Text(
          "Text in bottom",
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the widgets which needs to be at the top inside another Column widget, thereby making the root widget containing only two children. 1st child containing all the widgets which need to be aligned at the top and the 2nd child containing widget which is to be placed at the bottom. Now you use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to align 1st child to the top and second to the bottom.

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ChildA(),
        ChildB(),
      ]
    ),
    BottomAlignedChild(),
 ]
);
```