# how to center FloatingActionButton inside the persistentFooterButtons

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Can someone explain to me how can i center the FloatingActionButton inside the persistentFooterButtons. im missing something here.

```
  List _footer() {
return <Widget>[
  new ButtonBar(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
              onPressed: () => {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
];}
```

===

```
 @override  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Question"),
  ),
  body: _body(),
  persistentFooterButtons: _footer(),
);  }
```

Comment: Can you please share the image what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the code of Scaffold, below is how persistentFooterButtons created:

```dart
new Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    border: new Border(
      top: Divider.createBorderSide(context, width: 1.0),
    ),
  ),
  child: new SafeArea(
    child: new ButtonTheme.bar(
      child: new SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: new ButtonBar(
          children: widget.persistentFooterButtons
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

You can see here, your buttons are wrapped by a ButtonBar. Now let's look at the ButtonBar code below, the DEFAULT alignment is **MainAxisAlignment.end**. I guess this follows the Material guidelines.

```dart
const ButtonBar({
  Key key,
  this.alignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  this.mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  this.children: const <Widget>[],
}) : super(key: key);
```

The Flutter framework is being updated, but till **today (2018 June 08th)**, you can not put the buttons to the center using persistentFooterButtons.

**Solution:** I suggest you follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50508152/how-to-align-a-columns-child-to-the-bottom) to put your buttons at the center-bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

I found an easy solution is to wrap the FloatingActionButton in a sized box that is the same width as the screen.

```
      persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: FloatingActionButton(

            onPressed: () {
              print('Close pressed');
            },
            child: Text('Close'),
          )
        )
      ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I achieved the desired result with this:

```
persistentFooterButtons: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.width,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Your centered button'),
                  onPressed: (){},
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ]
```

I've used a flatbutton just as example but it works as well with floatinActionButtons.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Found yet another solution. MaterialTheme (theme_data.dart) has buttonBarTheme attribute. You can modify it like following:

```
var myTheme = ThemeData(
    buttonBarTheme: ButtonBarThemeData(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    ),
)
```

And specify it in your MaterialApp widget:

```
MaterialApp(theme: myTheme)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying something similar, but instead of a FloatingActionButton, a set of, let's say two ElevatedButtons, you can center them like this:

```
...
persistentFooterButtons: [
  Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(), //Button 1
        SizedBox(),
        ElevatedButton(), //Button 2
      ],
    ),
  ),
],
...
```

In hope that anyone might find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`floatingActionButton` can be aligned or positioned by making use of `floatingActionButtonLocation` property, however it is not useful for button placed inside `persistentFooterButtons`.

The `persistentFooterButtons` are wrapped inside `ButtonBar` and we don't have any way to override the `ButtonBar` default alignment of `MainAxisAlignment.end` for `persistentFooterButtons`.

Flutter team could have provided `persistentFooterButtonsAlignment` property but without it, one can achieve similar layout using following `bottomNavigationBar` hack, if it is not already being used for something else.

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
        Divider(
            height: 0,
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FlatButton(
                child: Text('Button'),
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 12.0),
                textColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
                onPressed: () {},
            ),
        ),
    ],
),
```