# How to use Expanded in SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: flutter

How to use `Expanded` in `SingleChildScrollView`? I have a screen with `Image.network`, `ListView.builder` and `Row` (`TextFormField` and `IconButton`). I wrapped `ListView` with `Expanded`. How to wrap this column with `SingleChildScrollView`? I need to move screen when the keyboard is open to see what I am writing. When I wrap my column I have this error.

```dart
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child:
                Image.network(
                  postOne.imageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  height: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width,
                  width: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width,
                ),
                onLongPress: () {},
                onDoubleTap: () {},
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.33,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: commentList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                        onLongPress: () {},
                        child: Card(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: new CheckboxListTile(
                                title: new Text(commentList
                                    .elementAt(position)
                                    .coment,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                                value: values[commentList
                                    .elementAt(position)
                                    .coment],
                                onChanged: (bool value) {}),
                          ),
                        )
                    );
                  }
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    new Flexible(
                      child: Theme(
                        data: new ThemeData(
                            brightness: Brightness.light,
                            primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
                            inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme(
                              labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black45, fontSize: 18.0
                              ),
                            )
                        ),
                        child: new Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: new TextFormField(
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Please enter the comment';
                              }
                            },
                            controller: commentController,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Add comment",
                              //hintText: 'Add comment'
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 12.0),
                        child: new IconButton(
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.black,),
                            onPressed: () {}
                        )
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

```
I/flutter ( 6816): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6816): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 6816): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter ( 6816): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
I/flutter ( 6816): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
I/flutter ( 6816): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter ( 6816): space in the vertical direction.
I/flutter ( 6816): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
I/flutter ( 6816): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
I/flutter ( 6816): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
I/flutter ( 6816): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
I/flutter ( 6816): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
I/flutter ( 6816): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
I/flutter ( 6816): constraints provided by the parent.
I/flutter ( 6816): The affected RenderFlex is:
I/flutter ( 6816):   RenderFlex#9f534 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 6816): The creator information is set to:
I/flutter ( 6816):   Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#3670d] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
I/flutter ( 6816):   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#4878e] ←
I/flutter ( 6816):   Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#c5885] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ←
I/flutter ( 6816):   ⋯
I/flutter ( 6816): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is:
I/flutter ( 6816):   _RenderSingleChildViewport#155d8 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 6816):   creator: _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#3670d] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
I/flutter ( 6816):   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#4878e] ←
I/flutter ( 6816):   Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#c5885] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ←
I/flutter ( 6816):   RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 6816):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter ( 6816):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=440.8, 0.0<=h<=649.3)
I/flutter ( 6816):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 6816): See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
I/flutter ( 6816): If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
I/flutter ( 6816):   https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
I/flutter ( 6816):   http://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
I/flutter ( 6816): If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:
I/flutter ( 6816):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 6816):
```

[image: screen]

Comment: You cant combine singlechildscroolview -> column -> expanded whitout give a height. Wrap you singlechildscroolview in a container or sizedbox with  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.

Comment: If I understood correctly [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition/ensureVisible.html) is what you are looking for...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71260393/7706354

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The answer is in the error itself. When the column is inside a view that is scrollable, the column is trying to shrink-wrap its content but since you used `Expanded` as a child of the column it is working opposite to the column trying to shrink-wrap its children. This is causing this error because these two directives are completely opposite to each other.

As mentioned in the error logs try the following:

Consider setting `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min` (for column) and using `FlexFit.loose` fits for the flexible(use `Flexible` rather than `Expanded`).

Comment: Can you add some words to explain why it those two params it works?

Comment: I simply figured out a way to get rid of Expanded. Then minAxisSize worked for me.

Comment: Thank you.. spend hours to solve this issue.

Answer (score 393):

Instead of using `SingleChildScrollView`, It's easier to use `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverFillRemaining`.

Try this:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Header'),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
          const Text('Footer'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Not sure if the effect is intended, but the Expanded widget will shrink if you open keyboard on the page.

Comment: `CustomScrollView` doesn't respect keyboard overflow

Comment: this is the best solution as it doesn't miss up your column layout and `IntrinsicHeight`

Comment: Slim and robust solution. My text can stay centered with a widget pushed to top and bottom of the screen, while the scrolling still works, whenever the text is too long for the screen. Thanks!

Comment: This is excellent for web pages where the bottom bar sticks to the bottom. Thank you so much for solving this issue for me.

Comment: This can be used not only for Column and Expanded, but also for e.g. Center widget, when you need to fill the page with one element, but make it scrollable. Perfect answer, many thanks!

Comment: This remains scrollable even if it doesn't exceed the parent's height, which is the only reason to use SingleChildScrollView imo.

Answer (score 216):

Try this,

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraint) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraint.maxHeight),
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Header"),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
              Text("Footer"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

I got this solution from git issues when I get into the same situation. I don't have the git link. I think it may help you.

**Reusable widget:**

**Note:** use it, only if one of the children is `Expanded`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollColumnExpandable extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  final CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment;
  final MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment;
  final VerticalDirection verticalDirection;
  final TextDirection textDirection;
  final TextBaseline textBaseline;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

  const ScrollColumnExpandable({
    Key key,
    this.children,
    CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment,
    MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment,
    VerticalDirection verticalDirection,
    EdgeInsetsGeometry padding,
    this.textDirection,
    this.textBaseline,
  })  : crossAxisAlignment = crossAxisAlignment ?? CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment = mainAxisAlignment ?? MainAxisAlignment.start,
        verticalDirection = verticalDirection ?? VerticalDirection.down,
        padding = padding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final children = <Widget>[const SizedBox(width: double.infinity)];

    if (this.children != null) children.addAll(this.children);
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: padding,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: constraint.maxHeight - padding.vertical,
              ),
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: crossAxisAlignment,
                  mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  verticalDirection: verticalDirection,
                  children: children,
                  textBaseline: textBaseline,
                  textDirection: textDirection,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: constraint.maxHeight is not recognizeable in my code!!

Comment: @evals you forgot copy LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraint)

Comment: This was such a life saver, thank you so much! IntrinsicHeight was the missing piece for me.

Comment: I believe this is the git issue you were referring to:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18711

Comment: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
The offending constraints were:
  BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=1200.0, h=Infinity)

Comment: How to make room for the keypad in this code(autoscrolls the page and bring the widget in question into view and the keypad below it). Adding the viewinsets didn't help, it overflowed.

Comment: You don't need the `IntrinsicHeight`. the `constraints` does the job.

Comment: Using `IntrinsicHeight` caused an exception `RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions` so I replaced it with `Container( height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height...` and it worked.

Comment: Great solution, although IntrinsicHeight  is by documentation "relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible." And in my case IntrinsicHeight is a must, not like @Vahid says.

Comment: This solution does not work if the keyboard is on the screen.

Comment: Bro, this widget literally saved me! For my whole entire life I've been wondering how to add space, but make it tiny and scrollable when the device is small. Thank YOU

Comment: can anyone give an explanation of why this works?, i read the docs on IntrisicHeight but i don't still get it.

Answer (score 53):

I tried Vijaya Ragavan solution but did some adjustments to it & it still works.
To use `Expanded` with `SingleChildScrollView`, I used `ConstrainedBox` and set its height to the height of the screen (using `MediaQuery`). You'll just need to make sure the screen content you put inside `ConstrainedBox` is not bigger than the height of the screen.

Otherwise set the height of `ConstrainedBox` to height of the content you want to display on the screen.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: Text('Hello World!'),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    )
)
```

**Edit:**
To subtract the height of the `AppBar` and/or the Status Bar, see below:

```dart
double screenHeightMinusAppBarMinusStatusBar = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height 
    - appBar.preferredSize.height
    - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
```

Comment: LayoutBuilder will actually give you the remaining space your SingleChildScrollView can have. MediaQuery.of(context).size.height will give you the total device screen height (where the AppBar already took some space)

Comment: LayoutBuilder sounds better indeed.
But if someone wants to use MediaQuery, you will need to subtract the AppBar height (if SingleChildScrollView is a widget child of a Scaffold that has an appBar) and/or subtract the status/notification bar height (if SingleChildScrollView is a child widget of a SafeArea) from the total screen height, for example like this: 
`double screenHeightMinusAppBarMinusStatusBar = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - appBar.preferredSize.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top`

Comment: well, I am getting a syntax error it tells me that " undefined name appBar"

Comment: So basically he use a Expanded to fit the entire height dinamically, and you set a fixed height. Your'e such a genius

Answer (score 18):

Simply wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` in a `Center` or an `Align` element.

Example :

```dart
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

or

```dart
  Center(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Using `Center` actually worked for me.
`Scaffold(Center(Scrollbar(SingleChildScrollView(Container(...)))))`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: very smart approach

Comment: If use Center => Center will center all items in SingleChildScrollView, this way cause the display of this item list not to be in the correct position as we want like: padding, aligntment.
So, I recommend use Align (alignment: Alignment.topCenter) or SizedBox(height: double.infinity) to cover child is SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: Wouldn't have expected that it works, but it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can simply wrap the column in a sized box and give it a `width` and `height` as shown:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container() //widget here
              const Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(),
              ),
              Container() //widget here
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Breaks with keyboard functionality fyi

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out, because you are using a scrollable, you can't expand to the infinity (*theoretically  speaking*), that's what's happening when you try to expand your `ListView` that is nested in a `SingleChildScrollView`.

You can try using a `NestedScrollView`, or, if it fits your demands and because you have commented out this line:

```
//height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.33,
```

You can just wrap your `ListView` in a `ConstrainedBox` (or even just a regular `Container`) with that height, for example, instead of the `Expanded`, like so:

```
 Container(
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.33,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: commentList.length,
                ...
               )
          )
```

Since you are already in a scrollable, you shouldn't have issues with smaller screens, because the whole tree is scrollable.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers are not taken into account wich you have a textfield widget, so when the keyboard open you will get a problem with the size of your content (it will be heigher than the screen), so you should to wrap one of the widgets inside the (expanded) at least with (flexible).

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    body:CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: false,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const TextField(),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                         children: [
                           Flexible(child: someWidget()),
                                   ]
                             )
                      ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to only apply the ScrollView when you need to, and otherwise to let the content expand.

Something like this works well:

```
class ConstrainedFlexView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double minSize;
  final Axis axis;

  const ConstrainedFlexView(this.minSize, {Key key, this.child, this.axis}) : super(key: key);

  bool get isHz => axis == Axis.horizontal;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, constraints) {
        double viewSize = isHz ? constraints.maxWidth : constraints.maxHeight;
        if (viewSize > minSize) return child;
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: axis ?? Axis.vertical,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: isHz ? double.infinity : minSize, 
                maxWidth: isHz ? minSize : double.infinity),
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
ConstrainedFlexView(600, child: FlexContent())
```

This will flex to fill all vertical space, but once the widget is <600px it will switch to a constrained box + scroll view, allowing the content not to be squished too much.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is:

- Being able to use expanded inside the SingleChildScrollView to fill the remaining screen.
- Not being bothered by the keyboard either hidding the TextFormField you are writing into either resizing the content of the SingleChildScrollView.

I had the same problem.
Here is a maybe hazardous but in my case working solution I used:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FiniteSizeSingleChildScrollViewNotBotheredByKeyboard
    extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const FiniteSizeSingleChildScrollViewNotBotheredByKeyboard(
      {Key? key, required this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FiniteSizeSingleChildScrollViewNotBotheredByKeyboard> createState() =>
      _FiniteSizeSingleChildScrollViewNotBotheredByKeyboardState();
}

class _FiniteSizeSingleChildScrollViewNotBotheredByKeyboardState
    extends State<FiniteSizeSingleChildScrollViewNotBotheredByKeyboard> {
  double width = 0, height = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      if (width != constraints.maxWidth) {
        width = constraints.maxWidth;
        height = constraints.maxHeight;
      }
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: width,
          height: height,
          child: widget.child,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

The idea is to get the available size just before the SingleChildScrollView, and then to inject this size into a SizedBox which is inside the SingleChildScrollView. Also, to avoid the keyboard changing this size, there is a if condition which prevents changing the height if the width has not changed.

The only issue I uncontered yet with this custom widget, is that if a TextFormField controller inside this widget (lets call it widget A) call setState on a widget B containing this widget A which itself is a child of the keyed Form associated with the TextFormField, The contoller will trigger a rebuild at the same time as the keyboard will trigger a rebuild of the widget A, which generate an exception. To avoid this put the keyed Form inside the widget A (and not above).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem that a widget within the sub tree of the `SliverFillRemaining` / `IntrinsicHeight` was using a `LayoutBuilder`. And `LayoutBuilder` cannot be used in any widget tree that calculates its intrinsic dimensions (You will get an error saying that `LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions`).

Since `SliverFillRemaining` with `hasScrollBody: false` also calculates the intrinsic dimensions of its child, it cannot be combined with any descendant widget that uses `LayoutBuilder`.

It is therefore not possible to combine both options in the same widget sub tree.

If your layout, however, does not use `LayoutBuilder` as a descendant of the `SliverFillRemaining` / `IntrinsicHeight` widget, but somewhere else in the scroll view, you can simply put it in a different sliver. Example reusing tanghao's code could look like this:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    // Use SliverList or any different sliver to display the children that use LayoutBuilder
    SliverList(
       delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(childrenContainingLayoutBuilder),
    ),
    // Use the SliverFillRemaining for the sub tree that uses Expanded / Flexible / Spacer etc.
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Header'),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
          const Text('Footer'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok since no one has mentioned something similar. if your use case involves putting a single button at the bottom of the screen (like you are trying to design a login page), and I suppose this is what OP wants to achieve, consider using `FloatingActionButton` with a typical `Column` or `ListView`. the pros of this approach are obvious, the code is so simple, you won't face any problems with the keyboard.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScrollableWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //make sure the button is at the bottom of the screen, make it afloat
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      //Wrap the button with SizedBox(width: double.infinity,)
      // if you want it to fill the full screen's width, use Padding with SizedBox
      floatingActionButton:
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Sign In")),
      body: const Column(
        children: [
          //First Child
          //Second Child
          //...
          //..
          //Nth Child
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to use upper case when starting a new sentence.