# SizedBox which height is the maximum of the screen size or child

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to create a SizedBox which the height is the highest value between the screen size or its child? I want to have an Expanded widget inside a SingleScrollView, and I want its child to be sized with at least the screen height, but at maximum the child height.

Comment: I found the answer to my question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62097942/8633918

Comment: That's nice but you have to convert your widgets into slivers. I would recommend using SliverToBoxAdapter to convert any box layout widget such as sizedbox, container, row, etc. into a sliver compatible widget.