# Proper way of giving space between title and form?

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve a layout that looks like this.

[image: expected result]

It works fine until I do focus on the input.

[image: unexpected result]

I wonder how to do this in a proper way... Here is what I already tried so far:

1. Wrapping form inside `SingleChildScrollView` (`Spacer` widget causing error).
2. Using `CustomScrollView`, (`Spacer` widget causing error).
3. Wrapping `CustomScrollView` or `SingleChildScrollView` inside `SizedBox` limited by device's height (causing some element only partially visible on smaller devices).
4. Following the answer [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326005/how-to-use-expanded-in-singlechildscrollview) (doesn't work).

Any clue? Here is my code:

```dart
class CreateFieldReportPage extends GetView<CreateFieldReportController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: controller.focusScope.unfocus,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                PageHeader(
                  helper: 'fieldReport.create.helper'.tr,
                  title: 'fieldReport.create'.tr,
                ),
                Spacer(),
                FieldReportForm(),
                PageNavigator(
                  onPressedPrimaryButton: () {
                    Get.toNamed(Routes.EVENT_CREATE_ADD_USER);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: SingleChildScrollView should be at the top, have you added at the top, if not works try it by removing SafeArea

Comment: I did, still can't give a spacer between the title and the form

Comment: Try by removing the ```spacer``` and instead of this add the ```mainAxisAlignment``` in your ```Column``` and try to give spacing using ```spaceBetween```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spacer()` behaves like a `Flexible` widget which will occupy only available space on the screen, if other widgets occupied the remaining space then it will not going to work.

For you, `SizedBox(height: 30)`, would work and add the required height. `SingleChildScrollView()` will provide additional space then and perform scrolling.

Comment: Agreed, it somehow works but in smaller devices, the form is cut off and user needs to scroll down the rest. I was thinking about more flexible way to do it without having to worry about it. How do you think?

Comment: use MediaQuery and add respective size. It will take care of device dimensions.