# SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, reorderable-list

Encounter this error if added `SingleChildScrollView`
In my screen it will still have others widgets as well, that's why i need to make my screen scrollable

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollController: ScrollController(),
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: object.length,
                  onReorder:onReorder,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return...
                  },),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Why not just returning ReordableListView.builder() and forget about the rest? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make my whole screen scrollable, i still have others widgets

Comment: ok but then you cannot wrap the ReordableListView with an Expanded. Because SibgleChilScrollView has the possibility to go to infinity. Therefore your ReordableListView will be infinite. So tell me you want the ReoradableListview to cover how much of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Either set height to your ReorderableListView:

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  child: ReorderableListView(...
...
```

Or check this:
[How to use Expanded in SingleChildScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326005/how-to-use-expanded-in-singlechildscrollview)