# Flutter SingleChildScrollView with Expanded

Tags: flutter, flutter-renderflex-error

How do you guys solve the following Flutter layout??

I have a screen, where I have to show, as described in the picture: a logo + 3 TextFormFields + 2 buttons + a Container.

[image]

Problems:

1. I need to put all the widgets inside a `Column` and, the Column inside a `SingleChildScrollView` so that, when the keyboard pops up, it does not cover the `TextFields`.
2. The last widget, the `Container`, shall take all the remaining screen space on the bottom, but NOT taking more than the screen size. For that, My idea was to use the `Expanded` widget, so that the Container can expand to the bottom of the screen, but that gives an error:

`The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

So I guess my question, in short is, how do I prevent the keyboard to cover the TextFields, while at the same time I force the Container to take all the remaining space on the bottom.

That was my attempt:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Image.asset("assets/images/appLogo.png"),
        TextFormField(),
        TextFormField(),
        TextFormField(),
        Row(children: [TextButton(), TextButton()]),
        Expanded(child: Container())
      ],
    ));
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326005/how-to-use-expanded-in-singlechildscrollview and multiple ways to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

`Expanded` doesn't know how much size to take. Also the other children don't know their exact size.

Wrap your Image inside a container and give height & width to it. also try wrapping all textfields inside a column or container each.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
  children: [
    Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).Size.width * 0.4,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).Size.height * 0.2,
    child: Image.asset("assets/images/appLogo.png"),
    ),
    Column(
    children: [ 
    TextFormField(),
    TextFormField(),
    TextFormField(),]
    )
    Row(children: [TextButton(), TextButton()]),
    Expanded(child: Container())
  ],
));
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will give it a try and comment again