# Flutter : Error after add Spacer() in my row Children

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I do a row for many button that can do scroll vertical, but i need some space between button, so i add Spacer() for create a space

```
            SingleChildScrollView(
              .....
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                        ....
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      TextButton(
                        ....
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
```

After I add syntax Spacer() there, I got this Error
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnMZw.png),

Comment: Try changing mainAxisAlignment to MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, if that doesn't work you can try this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62097942/11891580)

Comment: I think issue is in your parent widget, Please show us the code with parent widget

Comment: I already find the solution guys, thx everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change my Row() to Wrap(), then I add spacing: from wrap widget

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 100,
  ....
)
```

and Done, Thx everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try to wràp your SingleChildScrollView with Container that has a preferred size, e.g. `Container(width: 400, height 400, child: SingleChilScrollView....)`. If it doesn't work, use SizedBox or Divider instead of Spacer.