# Fixing Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget in a Flutter Application

Tags: flutter

In my flutter screen I am trying to create a Card with title and below it iterate the data related to this title. I am currently getting the following error:

```
I/flutter ( 3496): Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
I/flutter ( 3496): The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
I/flutter ( 3496): Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
I/flutter ( 3496): The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a ConstrainedBox widget.
I/flutter ( 3496): The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
I/flutter ( 3496):   RichText ← Text ← Expanded ← FutureBuilder<List<AllActiveSessionsModel>> ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Expanded ← Row ← Padding ← Semantics ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 3496): #0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6042:11)
I/flutter ( 3496): #1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6059:6)
I/flutter ( 3496): #2      ParentDataElement._applyParentData.applyParentDataToChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5258:15)
I/flutter ( 3496): #3      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4931:14)
I/flutter ( 3496): #4      ParentDataElement._applyParentData.applyParentDataToChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5261:15)
I/flutter ( 3496): #5      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4931:14)
I/flutter ( 3496): #6      ParentDataElement._applyParentData (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5264:5)
I/flutter ( 3496): #7      ParentDataElement.notifyClients (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5308:5)
I/flutter ( 3496): #8      ProxyElement.updated (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5238:5)
I/flutter ( 3496): #9      ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5226:5)
I/flutter ( 3496): #10     Element.updateChild (package
```

I am not sure how to fix this error here is the UI code:

```
Builder(builder: (context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        // width: double.infinity, // Set the width of the container to be as wide as possible
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Container(
                        child: FutureBuilder(
                          future: _allActiveSessions,
                          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if ..............................
                                return Expanded(
                                  child: lastSession != null ? Text(DateFormat("d/MM").format(lastSession.endDate)) : Center(child: Text("")),
                                );
                              } else {
                                return Text("No Data");
                              }
                            } else {
                              return CircularProgressIndicator();
                            }
                          }, ),), ), ],),),
              for (var stuff in snapshot.stuff![index].stuff)
                Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          // flex: 2,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50, // set a fixed height for the container
                            width: 50, // set the width to 200 pixels

                            child: FutureBuilder(
                              future: _allActiveSessions,
                              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                    print("The error is ${snapshot.error}");
                                    return Text("Error/No Data");
                                  }
                                  if .......................................
                                        return Expanded(
                                          child: lastSession != null
                                              ? Text(filteredLogs.map((log) => "Some Data").join(", "))
                                              : Text("N/A"),
                                        );
                                    }
                                  } else {
                                    return Center(child: Text("N/A"));
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                }
                              },),), ),], ),),),], ),),),);  }),
```

My question how can I update the UI code so that it can show data using FutureBuilder to avoid the error of Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. My objective is to have a simplified data of dates or N/A nothing too long showing screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Expanded in SingleChildScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326005/how-to-use-expanded-in-singlechildscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an ***Expanded*** widget inside a ConstrainedBox, which is not allowed. The Expanded widget is to be used inside a Flex widget to take up available space. For fixing this error you need to move the Expanded widget to the appropriate place.