# SingleChildScrollView not scrolling - Flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollable, singlechildscrollview

I have a SingleChildScrollView widget inside a SafeArea that is not scrolling. I want to make all the screen scrollable, but it is not scrolling in no way.
Here is the code:

```
Scaffold(
   body: SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Column(
              children: [
                // some containers with text
                CustomList(),
                // some containers with text
                CustomList(),
                // some containers with text
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
     ),
     bottomSheet: // container and button
),
```

The CustomList is a Column widget with inside some Rows widgets like this:

```
Column(
   children:
      [
         // some rows like this, not only one
         Row(
            children: [
               Container(
                  child: CustomItem(),
               ),
         ],
    ],
  ),
];
)
```

CustomItem is only a Text. Why my screen is not scrollable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Expanded in SingleChildScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326005/how-to-use-expanded-in-singlechildscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

To make only scrollView scrollable

```
     physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), //add to ScrollView
```

and Other listViews should not be scrollable as only one parent should scroll

```
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),//add to ListView
```

also add Expanded to your listViews